# mod_rewrite How to hide "index.html"

Tags: mod-rewrite

i have a question about mod_rewrite.

this is my static html site architecture created with httrack:

```
http://www.example.com/index.html
http://www.example.com/example/index.html
http://www.example.com/example1/index.html
http://www.example.com/example2/example/index.html
http://www.example.com/example3/example/example/index.html
```

i want to hide all index.html in the browser url with mod_rewrite. like:

```
http://www.example.com/example2/example/
```

What is the mod_rewrite command for it?
After this action is complete it is necessary to rename my internal links?

Thanks for help :)

Comment: my site url is `http://www.example.com/example/index.html` i want to hide the index.html on every site

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the [DirectoryIndex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_dir.html) in your .htaccess file (from the root/document_root folder)

eg:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

Comment: sorry you dont undestand me... my english is bad :/
my sites are created with httrack and copied to the server and now i wanted to hide every index html with mod_rewrite in the url. is it possible?? thanks for help

Answer (score 3):

I have found the solution... I hope this is right:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*index\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

special thanks to book of zeus :)